# How can I glob a directory, sort the files by time/date, and print the names of the files in order?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm looking for a way to glob a directory and sort the contents by time/date and print it on the PHP page. There must be a way to do this, I've tried the following code but it won't print anything out on the page:

```
<?php
$files = glob("subdir/*");
$files = array_combine($files, array_map("filemtime", $files));
arsort($files);
?>
```

`print_r` wont work because I need just the file name. I'm new to PHP arrays so I need as much help as I can get!

Answer (score 2):

Given your original code:

```
$files = glob("subdir/*");
$files = array_combine($files, array_map("filemtime", $files));
arsort($files);
```

From there you could either loop on the array of sorted filename/mtime pairs, or create a new array with just the filenames (in their sorted order).

The first looks like:

```
foreach ($files as $file => $mtime) {
    echo $file . " ";
}
```

The second could be:

```
foreach (array_keys($files) as $file) {
    echo $file . " ";
}
```

Depending on your needs, it might also be okay to simply:

```
echo implode(" ", array_keys($files));
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're looking for `foreach`

```
foreach($files as $filename=>$mtime){
    echo AS INTENDED;
}
```

Comment: I am just getting numbers counting up to 15, why is this?